# systemctl short status output format for specific service

Tags: systemctl

is it possible to get status for specific systemd service

```
$ systemctl -a | grep sshd.service
  sshd.service              loaded    active   running   OpenSSH server daemon
$
```

but without grep, only with systemctl ? Something like `systemctl SHOW_STATUS_LIKE_A_OPTION sshd.service`

`systemctl status` - too long and multiline...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try `systemctl is-active sshd.service`, `systemctl is-enabled sshd.service` and `systemctl is-failed sshd.service`.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Samuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62025181/201665), I offer a simple shell function for `.bashrc`, including cheeky use of grep for colorization:

```
function status () {
    for name in $@; do \
      echo ${name} $(systemctl is-active ${name}) $(systemctl is-enabled ${name}); \
      done | column -t | grep --color=always '\(disabled\|inactive\|$\)'
}
```

Invocation:

```
> status ssh ntp snapd
ssh    active    enabled   
ntp    active    enabled   
snapd  inactive  disabled
```

Note that `is-active` will print `inactive` for non-existent services, while `is-enabled` will print a warning to `stderr`.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```bash
$ systemctl list-units -q amsd.service smad.service cpqIde.service cpqFca.service cpqiScsi.service cpqScsi.service
  amsd.service     loaded active running Agentless Management Service daemon
  cpqIde.service   loaded active running cpqIde MIB handler.
  cpqiScsi.service loaded active running cpqiScsi MIB handler.
  cpqScsi.service  loaded active running cpqScsi MIB handler.
  smad.service     loaded active running System Management Assistant daemon
```

To avoid having to provide the `.service` suffix, I tried `--type service`, with service names only, but got empty printout:

```bash
$ systemctl list-units --type service -q amsd smad cpqIde cpqFca cpqiScsi cpqScsi
$
```

The following works just as well:

```bash
(s=(amsd smad cpqIde cpqFca cpqiScsi cpqScsi); set -x; systemctl list-units -q ${s[@]/%/.service})
+ systemctl list-units -q amsd.service smad.service cpqIde.service cpqFca.service cpqiScsi.service cpqScsi.service
  amsd.service     loaded active running Agentless Management Service daemon
  cpqIde.service   loaded active running cpqIde MIB handler.
  cpqiScsi.service loaded active running cpqiScsi MIB handler.
  cpqScsi.service  loaded active running cpqScsi MIB handler.
  smad.service     loaded active running System Management Assistant daemon
```

I wish there were a way to include the "Since" field.

Answer (score 1):

The closest is native command is `systemctl list-units -t service`:

```
$ systemctl --user list-units --type service
  UNIT                    LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
  dbus.service            loaded active running D-Bus User Message Bus
  podman-promtail.service loaded active running rootless pod promtail

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
2 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Source: [Red Hat sys admin docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/managing-system-services-with-systemctl_configuring-basic-system-settings)